# Struts 2 : Rename / Replace the action name in URL with an Alias name

Tags: java, struts2

I am looking for a solution in Struts2 - java web application Code. I don't want the User to know the real 'action name' from the URL that gets executed in the backend Ex: If the action name is BillingPayment_Action then the URL will be www.Test.com/TestPackage/BillingPayment_Action
Instead i want to show the User an alias name in the URL : Ex dummy name PleasePayyourBill in the URL instead of the real action name www.Test.com/TestPackage/PleasePayyourBill

Comment: We're not here to write your code.

Comment: If you want to handle everything in Struts take a look at interceptors and action chaining.

Comment: It's unclear how and why do you want to show.

Comment: Yes. Sorry i am just asking about an idea how to do it . Not asking for the complete code . I will look at action chaining. One of the requirements we had was to hide the action name from the Users and instead use some other Generic name.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not wrong Strutus uses apache as web server. If it is really the case  in apache usually used  [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) module hide real requests URIs

You can find good examples here : https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^/PleasePayyourBill$ ./TestPackage/BillingPayment_Action
```

Comment: Thank You Daniel. We are using IBM websphere application server . Looks like mod_rewrite or other similar rewrites only add complexity. This requirement of us was to see if its possible in an easy way to rename the action name presented to the users in the URL .

Comment: Thank you too, but  you're right. The link in my post for too complex examples. I was lazy to add exact solution. Added  to post. I mean websphere as a application server still usually have web server in front of it. If this apache you can add mapping from my example in file .htaccess in root directory of your server. If it other server, you can still google for 'Pretty URL' - the technique used to hide real URLs